# Java Polynomial Addition

Tags: java, linked-list

I am using String Tokenizer and Linked Lists, and the Linked Lists are required for this assignment. There is an external file in there are numerous lines of polynomials (one per line). Using String Tokenizers and Linked List, I am running a while loop which captures two lines on each pass and adds them to linked lists. After the numbers have been loaded into linked lists, the goal is to add those polynomials together from their linked list and create a new linked list that contains that polynomial.

For example, first two lines in the file are this:

2x^4 -5x^3 +9x^2 -10

3x^4 -6x^3 +10x^2 -11

---

=
5x^4 -11x^3 +19x^2 -21

Here is my code:

```
public class PolynomialAddition
{
    static File dataInpt;
    static Scanner inFile;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
      dataInpt=new File("C:\\llpoly.txt");
      inFile=new Scanner(dataInpt);
      StringTokenizer myTokens;
      String line,polyTerm;
      Node firstL=new Node();
      Node secondL=new Node();
      line=inFile.nextLine();
      myTokens=new StringTokenizer(line);
      polyTerm=myTokens.nextToken();
      firstL.value=polyTerm.substring(0,polyTerm.indexOf("x"));
      firstL.value2=polyTerm.substring(polyTerm.indexOf("^")+1);

    }
}
```

Here is my node class:

```
public class Node
{
  public Object value;
  public Object value2;
  public Node next;

  public Node()
  {
    value=null;
    value2=null;
    next=null;
  }
  public Node (Object value, Object value2, Node next)
  {
    this.value=value;
    this.value2=value2;
    this.next=next;
  }
}
```

The problem comes after this where some lines are not complete while the line they have to be added to is complete like -12x^8 +5x^2 -3 and 8x^3 +2x

The answer to this is supposed to be -12x^8 +8x^3 +5x^2 +2x -3

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after lenghty labour in the chat, this is what 'we' came up with. I realize this is just blurting the answer, to an extent.

Even so, having a solid implementation in clean style Java 1.4 code could do a lot to help your understanding.

Special attention has been given to printing the result in tabulated form, aligning terms of different operand in the columns of their respective exponent.

### Code

There are two files:

#### Node.java

```
class Node {
    int factor;
    int exponent;
    Node next;

    public Node() {
        factor = 0;
        exponent = 0;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(int factor, int exponent, Node next) {
        this.factor = factor;
        this.exponent = exponent;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%+4dx^%d    ", new Integer[] { new Integer(factor), new Integer(exponent) }); 
    }
 }
```

#### PolynomialAddition.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PolynomialAddition {
    static File dataInpt;
    static Scanner inFile;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        dataInpt = new File("/tmp/input.txt");
        inFile = new Scanner(dataInpt);

        while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
            Node first = readPolynomial();
//          printList(first);

            Node second = readPolynomial();
//          printList(second);

            Node addition = addPolynomials(first, second);
//          printList(addition);

            printTabulated(first, second, addition);

            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    private static Node addPolynomials(Node first, Node second) {
        Node head = null, current = null;
        while (null!=first || null!=second)
        {
            boolean pickfirst = false;
            boolean haveBoth = (null!=first && null!=second);

            Node node;
            if (haveBoth && first.exponent == second.exponent)
            {
                node = new Node(first.factor + second.factor, first.exponent, null);
                first = first.next;
                second = second.next;
            } else
            {
                pickfirst = first!=null && 
                    ((second == null) || first.exponent > second.exponent);

                if (pickfirst)
                {
                    node = new Node(first.factor, first.exponent, null);
                    first = first.next;
                } else
                {
                    node = new Node(second.factor, second.exponent, null);
                    second = second.next;
                }
            }

            if (current == null)
            {
                head = node;
                current = head;
            } else
            {
                current.next = node;
                current = node;
            }
        }

        return head;
    }

    private static void printTabulated(Node first, Node second, Node addition) {
        String line1="", line2="", barline="", line3="";
        while (addition != null)
        {
            String 
                 part1 = "           ", 
                 part2 = "           ", 
                 part3 = "           ";

            if (null!=first && first.exponent == addition.exponent) 
            {
                part1 = first.toString();
                first = first.next;
            } 
            if (null!=second && second.exponent == addition.exponent) 
            {
                part2 = second.toString();
                second = second.next;
            }
            part3 = addition.toString();
            addition = addition.next;

            line1 += part1;
            line2 += part2;
            barline += "-----------";
            line3 += part3;
        }

        System.out.println(line1);
        System.out.println(line2);
        System.out.println(barline);
        System.out.println(line3);
    }

    private static Node readPolynomial() {
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer myTokens = new StringTokenizer(line);

        Node head = null, previous = null;
        while (myTokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            Node current = new Node();
            String term = myTokens.nextToken();

            if (term.startsWith("+"))
                term = term.substring(1);

            current.factor = Integer.parseInt(
                    term.substring(0, term.indexOf("x")));
            current.exponent = Integer.parseInt(
                    term.substring(term.indexOf("^") + 1));

            if (previous == null)
            {
                head = current;
                previous = head;
            } else
            {
                previous.next = current;
                previous = current;
            }
        }
        return head;
    }

    private static void printList(Node head) {
        for (Node ptr = head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.next)
            System.out.print(ptr);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

### Sample Data:

Input:

```
2x^4 -5x^3 +9x^2 -10x^0 
 3x^4 -6x^3 +10x^2 -11x^0 
 -2x^1 +4x^0 
 2x^1 -4x^0 
 8x^5 +6x^4 +5x^2 -3x^0 
 -12x^8 +2x^7 +14x^5 
 1x^5 +7x^2 +8x^1 
 -5x^4 -7x^3 -4x^2 -3x^0 
 10x^5 -3x^3 +4x^2 -234x^1 -12x^0 
 -5x^5 -2x^3 +10x^0
```

Output:

```
  +2x^4      -5x^3      +9x^2     -10x^0    
  +3x^4      -6x^3     +10x^2     -11x^0    
--------------------------------------------
  +5x^4     -11x^3     +19x^2     -21x^0    


  -2x^1      +4x^0    
  +2x^1      -4x^0    
----------------------
  +0x^1      +0x^0    


                        +8x^5      +6x^4      +5x^2      -3x^0    
 -12x^8      +2x^7     +14x^5                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------
 -12x^8      +2x^7     +22x^5      +6x^4      +5x^2      -3x^0    


  +1x^5                            +7x^2      +8x^1               
             -5x^4      -7x^3      -4x^2                 -3x^0    
------------------------------------------------------------------
  +1x^5      -5x^4      -7x^3      +3x^2      +8x^1      -3x^0    


 +10x^5      -3x^3      +4x^2    -234x^1     -12x^0    
  -5x^5      -2x^3                           +10x^0    
-------------------------------------------------------
  +5x^5      -5x^3      +4x^2    -234x^1      -2x^0
```

Comment: Despite all your hard work, I can't morally upvote a complete working answer for a homework question. :(  Maybe if it was written in a different language...

Comment: @MooingDuck that has gotten some compensation (explanation [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7709/discussion-between-user1079641-and-simchona)) which also uncovered a bug due to unnecessary cleverness. (obviously, fixed now) Thx for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I'd completely drop the linked-list approach. Or if you have to use it, use it as an input to the following approach.

Pre-allocate an array with some upper bound on size, then use the indices of the array as the exponent of `x` and at the corresponding index/exponent you store the coefficient of the term. So when you parse `2x^3` you say `polysum[3] += 2` (assuming the array was initialized with `0`). If you do this for both polynomials with the same polysum array, you will get an array containing the coefficients of the sum of the two polynomials.

Then you have to create the corresponding output which is the equivalent of, mathematically speaking: `polysum[0] + polysum[1] * x + polysum[2] * x^2` etc.

In case you may have to handle totally arbitrary exponents and pre-allocation of an array is infeasible, use a HashMap where the key is the exponent, and value is the coefficient.

Edit: If you **really** have to solve it by using your linked list, sort the two lists, and then iterate through the lists in parallel. In Python-like pseudo-code:

```
poly1_node = poly1_first_node
poly2_node = poly2_first_node
result_node = result_first_node
while poly1_node != Null and poly2_node != Null:
    if poly1_node.value2 == poly2_node.value2:
        result_node.value2 = poly1_node.value2
        result_node.value = poly1_node.value + poly2_node.value
        poly2_node = poly2_node.next
        poly2_node = poly2_node.next
    if poly1_node.value2 < poly2_node.value2:
        result_node.value2 = poly1_node.value2
        result_node.value = poly1_node.value
        poly1_node = poly1_node.next
    if poly2_node.value2 < poly1_node.value2:
        result_node.value2 = poly2_node.value2
        result_node.value = poly2_node.value
        poly2_node = poly2_node.next
    result_node.next = new Node()
    result_node = result_node.next
while poly1_node != Null:
    result_node.value2 = poly1_node.value2
    result_node.value = poly1_node.value
    poly1_node = poly1_node.next
    result_node.next = new Node()
    result_node = result_node.next
while poly2_node != Null:
    result_node.value2 = poly2_node.value2
    result_node.value = poly2_node.value
    poly2_node = poly2_node.next
    result_node.next = new Node()
    result_node = result_node.next
```

If you know the input is always sorted, you can skip the sorting. Otherwise, the sorting will be non-trivial.

Comment: Although I appreciate your answer, it doesn't answer my question

Comment: @user1079641: why doesn't it answer the question?  It looks good to me.

Comment: I have to use linked list and I am a student...this code is a little advanced and out of my understanding...Unless you are willing to come to a chat room with me and explain the code to me, I can't accept this.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend array or arraylist, using array index as polynomial exponential, and the array value as coefficients of the polinomials.

For example, 
    3+ 4*x+ 5*x^4
would be 
    3 4 0 0 5
for the arraylist.

It would be better if you create a class called Polynomial, and define the actions of it. Instead of using Node as a class.

Answer (score 1):

3x^3 - x^1 is the same thing as 3x^3 + 0x^2 - x^1 + 0. Try padding every value that way as you read it in.

Comment: I can't add them in...if they don't match up, both of them need to printed.

Answer (score 1):

This makes the assumption that the polynomials are written in exponent-descending form:
(Let me know if that is not the case!)

As you read in the elements in a line, check that the exponent of the current element is exactly one less than the previous element. If they are, then there is no problem. If they are not, take this approach:

Let `a` be the current element's exponent and `b` be the previous element's exponent.

Then use this code example to fix this:

```
for(int i = b - 1; i > a; i--)
{
    //Insert an element of the form: 0*x^i.
}
```

Comment: Here is what I have in my mind, I am using a linked list that captures each number (coefficient and exponent) from the line as using String Tokenizer but I am not sure how I would go about creating two different linked lists that work for the two different lines and at the end add them up.

Comment: Why create two lists? Just make one as I described!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with approach using array but can't we optimize more in terms of space complexity if we use hashmap.

So each polynomial equation will be a hashmap where key will be the exponent of x and value will be the cofficient of x.

Now you cam simply iterate through keys of one hashmap and add it to other hashmap.